# How to test SQL Server connection properties

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, sqljdbc

I have a Java application that interacts with a SQL Server database. I want to write some unit tests to test the connection [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-2017) like lockTimeout, queryTimeout, loginTimeout and socketTimeout etc.

What would be the best way to test the above scenarios? One approach would be to write code for each situation, prepare the situation and run that piece of code. It will be a kind of manual testing more. Is there any other way/ library to test SQL Server properties?

Comment: You shouldn't be testing them at all, unless you're the one who wrote the database driver.

Comment: This looks more like an integration test rather than unit test. If your goal is to test code that handles those exceptions, consider mocking the database,

Answer (score 0):

You can run queries on the SQL server to determine the config:

```
--Determine Lock Timeout:
SELECT @@LOCK_TIMEOUT AS LockTimeout

--Determine Remote Query Timeout:
EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout'

--Determine Remote Login Timeout:
EXEC sp_configure 'remote login timeout'
```

The connection / Socket timeout is set in the connection string, so you should already know that.

Comment: Those queries do not apply to the application API settings; they only return the configured values on the server for linked server queries.

Comment: That's what he asked for, the configured server values... There is no API for SQL Server, unless you consider ADODB a type of API? I mean I guess it kind of is.

Comment: The OP is talking about the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes, ADODB is an API but not related to this JDBC question. All of the settings in the question relate to the JDBC client driver. The settings in your answer relate to OLE DB settings on the server, not the client, and have no affect on JDBC.

Comment: So you're saying the remote query timeout setting and lock_timeout setting have no effect on remote queries being run over JDBC? Interesting.